# How can I list the contents of an SD card connected to Linux via a phone in USB Mass Storage Mode?

Tags: linux, mobile, usb, sd-card, usb-mass-storage

Is it possible to get a list of files from an SD card when it is connected as a USB Mass Storage device?

Comment: SD cards can't be connected as a UMS device. Did you mean the reader?

Comment: I meant SD card inserted in a phone and accessed on PC as a UMS device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UMS provides the contents of the SD card as a raw storage device, much the same as a hard drive or CD driver. As such, it is up to the operating system's VFS to make sense of the partitioning, formatting, and directory structure contained on it.

Comment: Does this mean that whenever the SD card (on phone) is accessed in UMS mode, the raw contents of the SD card will be read again and displayed on the PC?

Comment: It should, for a certain value of "displayed".

Comment: ok. well im facing a problem of sd card contents (on phone) not being seen on PC (when connected as UMS device). however if the same card is inserted in a Card Reader the content is seen. inserting it back in the phone will show the contents on PC. what could be the problem here.. any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a flaky card to me.

Comment: well i wouldnt blame the card if 10 diff cards in 10 phones end up giving the same problem ;)